Query using multiple links in Objectbox
I have these 2 entities in objectbox:
@Entity()
class Account {
  @Id()
  int id = 0;
}


@Entity()
class Transaction {

  @Id()
  int id = 0;

  final fromAccount = ToOne<Account>();
  final toAccount = ToOne<Account>();
}

I need to query all transactions from or to a particular account. I'm unable to figure out the query. Tried this but it doesn't work:
Future<List<Transaction>> getAllTransactionsForAccount(int accountId) {
    QueryBuilder<Transaction> builder = box.query();
    builder.link(
        Transaction_.toAccount, Account_.id.equals(accountId));
    builder.link(
        Transaction_.fromAccount, Account_.id.equals(accountId));
    Query<Transaction> q = builder.build();
    return q.findAsync();
  }

If I remove one of the builder.link for fromAccount or toAccount, it works, but I need both, not just one.
Could someone help please ?

Here's how you can do it:
Query for transactions where fromAccount matches the given accountId.
Query for transactions where toAccount matches the given accountId.
Combine the results of the two queries.

Your query looks fine. I also quickly wrote a test to verify that this works (https://gist.github.com/greenrobot-team/e5633d05a58fce14ea435e0db2dc491a). Maybe the data is not as expected? Maybe have a look using the Admin tool: https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser
If that won't work, please submit an issue and example that reproduces this to https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues

@Uwe-ObjectBox I'll file an issue, the data exists as I'm able to fetch it when I use just one link in the query.

@EfrosIonelu yes, I've already worked around the issue for now using this method but it's not ideal as I the list is quite large and I have to sort the combined list manually in the main thread since the query doesn't work.
